# Duplicate focus window with all elements with option edition

Tags: c#, winforms

I need create button thanks for we can duplicate focus Form with all elements which are inside and present the same in the new window.
What's more I need change value for example in my PictureBox for the copied window.
Maybe somebody explain me how to do it using C#?

For example this is the `FormResult` Form and I need duplicate that:

```
var mainForm = new APOForm();

// Generate PictureBox
pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(mainForm.getMyPath());
pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
pictureBox.Show();

// Change image for bitmap array
Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)pictureBox.Image;

// Create table for pixel value for histogram
int[] valueHistogram = new int[MAX_VALUE+1];

for(int i=0; i<MAX_VALUE; ++i)
{
    valueHistogram[i] = 0;
}

for (int x=0; x<bm.Width; ++x)
{
    for(int y=0; y<bm.Height; ++y)
    {
        Color c = bm.GetPixel(x, y);
        valueHistogram[c.R] += 1;
    }
}

// Generate histogram
histogram.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = MIN_VALUE;
histogram.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = MAX_VALUE;
histogram.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
histogram.Series.Clear();
histogram.Series.Add("S");
histogram.Series["S"].IsVisibleInLegend = false;

int maxAxisY = 0;

for (int i=0; i<256; ++i)
{
    if(maxAxisY < valueHistogram[i]) { maxAxisY = valueHistogram[i];  }

    histogram.Series["S"].Points.AddXY(i, valueHistogram[i]);  
}

histogram.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = maxAxisY;
histogram.Show();
```

Comment: You are going to need to flesh out that question a bit if you want anyone to answer it.  Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  This site works much better when you write up some code and show it as part of your question

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for information, now I add some code with better present situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you want to show a second form that is "identical" to the form the user is currently looking at, but with a different value in a picturebox right?

You can do this to solve that problem:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public string changeTextBoxValue { set { textBox1.Text = value; } }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCreateCopiedWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 secondForm = new Form1();
        secondForm.changeTextBoxValue = "Different value for second form";

        secondForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Instead of using a TextBox you would have your picturebox and would change the image using the property, but the idea is the same. You instantiate the same form and change the values you need and then show it to the user.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! But I have only one question... how create identical window for focus window because now we have set for rigidly. Sorry for my English :D

Comment: What do you mean by "focus window"?  Are you just saying "when the second form opens, we want the focus to be on the same control as it was on in the first window".  The tricky part of that is that the focus will be on the button you just clicked - you'll need to track the focus a bit to know what was the focused control right before the button was pressedddd